# How to set values to private variable in class where class constructor itself starting the thread?

Tags: java, junit, java-threads

Below is my source code class where class constructor starting the thread.But in run() it is checking for not null value of a varible.So in order to test the using junit that variable should not be null.

```
public class MainClass extends Thread {
    private SomeQue que;
    private static final String THREAD_NAME = "s_thread";
    private boolean isRunning = false;

    public MainClass () {
        setName(THREAD_NAME);
        setIsRunning(true);
        start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (isRunning()) {
            if (que!= null) {
                obj = que.pop();
                if (obj != null) {
                    //....
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If use

```
ReflectioinTerstUtils.setField(new MainClass(),"que",que);
```

we have to create the object to set data to variable to while creating object itself thread is getting started.So any ideas..

Comment: This is a bad design to be sure. Not only should you not be extending thread, but you shouldn't be starting the thread from within its own constructor.

Comment: So (1) set it in the constructor, or (2) don't start the thread in the constructor. This seems rather obvious. You also need to look into declaring `que` as `volatile`, and please note that the correct spelling is `queue`.

Comment: Code formatted for readability. In the future, please put in this effort yourself.

Comment: SomeQue  should be a constrcutor arg in MainThread, aka MainThread(SomeQue  queue){ this.que=queue ;....

Comment: @ akshaya pandey , that is the source code  and i'm doing code coverage activity so i can not chage the source code.Data coming to this from some where while application is running.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels. Do you mean code is not readable?

Comment: 1. If you can't change the source code this is not a programming question: 'any ideas' about *what* exactly? 2. Yes he did mean it is illegible. Look at those three `}` with the same levels of indentation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP states the source code can't be changed, which makes the question both unclear and not about computer programming.

Comment: @user207421 1. I mean I have to do code change in my test case not in source code.2.'any ideas'-- I have no idea for this scenario ,I need clue to proceed.

Comment: You can use sun.misc.Unsafe to create objects without calling their constructors. The problem with doing that is it’s an internal (deprecated?) API and the class fields will be initialized to their defaults (null,0,false,etc.)

Comment: @mae: it wasn't *easily* readable as your indentation, especially the curly brace indentation, was somewhat random. You don't want your code harder to read and understand than it has to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see around this (besides refactoring) is to create an instance of the object without calling the constructor. This can be done using the internal class [sun.misc.Unsafe](https://www.baeldung.com/java-unsafe):

**Note: the very name of this class tells you how powerful (and deadly) it can be. With great power comes great responsibility. Use wisely.**

```java
// Obtain the unsafe object without throwing a SecurityException (assuming no security manager)
Field field = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
field.setAccessible(true);
Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) field.get(null);

// Create the instance 
MainClass instance = (MainClass) unsafe.allocateInstance(MainClass.class); // Constructor is not called

// set isRunning if needed
// do junit stuff
```